# Promises not running T-SQL query in node js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, asynchronous, stored-procedures, promise

I am trying to write a function in node js that will run a SQL query using `mssql` and return a promise. For some reason it gets to the line

```
console.log("got to the run proc functions");
```

but won't run any code after that. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
runProc: function (params) {  
    var sql = require("mssql");
    sql.Promise = require('promise');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var dbConfig = {
        server:"ip",
        database: "db",
        user:"user",
        password: "pw"
    }

    console.log("got to the run proc functions");

    var keys = Object.keys(params);

    sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
            console.log("got connected");
            const request = pool.request()

            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

                if (keys[i].substring(0,6)=="Common") {
                    request.input(keys[i],sql.Bit,params[keys[i]]);
                    console.log("set the bit parameters");
                }
                else {
                    request.input(keys[i],params[keys[i]]);
                    console.log("set the other parameters");
                }
            } 

            request.execute("storedprocedure")
            return request;
        }).then(result => {
                resolve(result)
        }).catch(err => {
                reject(Error(err))
        });

        sql.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint or a `console.log` in the `catch` handler to check for an unsuccessful connection attempt to SQL Server.

Comment: The issue could be where you're calling `sql.close()` - your random indentation makes it look like it's inside the `.then(pool =>` code, but in actual fact it's not - so you call `sql.close` before you call `pool.request` ... also, avoid the Promise constructor anti-pattern ... sql.connect returns a promise, no need to wrap that code in a promise

Comment: Another issue is you are returning `request` rather than `request.execute()`

Answer (score 0):

Look where you call `sql.close()`. i.e. it's being called before `request=pool.request` etc! So, that would fail for a start.

Also, you are returning `request` (which isn't a promise) rather than `request.execute()` (which is a promise) so, the promise would resolve before `execute` completes

And finally, no need to wrap a promise inside a Promise constructor (not that this breaks your code, but there's no need for it)

Given all that, your code is

```
runProc: function (params) {  
    var sql = require("mssql");
    sql.Promise = require('promise');

    // removed new Promise constructor as sql.connect already returns a promise we can chain to and return
    var dbConfig = {
        server:"ip",
        database: "db",
        user:"user",
        password: "pw"
    }

    console.log("got to the run proc functions");

    var keys = Object.keys(params);

    return sql.connect(dbConfig)
    .then(pool => {
        console.log("got connected");
        const request = pool.request()

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

            if (keys[i].substring(0,6)=="Common") {
                request.input(keys[i],sql.Bit,params[keys[i]]);
                console.log("set the bit parameters");
            }
            else {
                request.input(keys[i],params[keys[i]]);
                console.log("set the other parameters");
            }
        } 
        // need to return the result of execute, not the request object
        return request.execute("storedprocedure")
    })
    .catch(err => throw new Error(err))
    // use Promise#finally - available in all good promise libraries
    .finally(sql.close); // sql.close AFTER we're done with it, not before
}
```

Using the sparkly new `async`/`await` promise sugar simplifies the code even more

```
runProc: async function (params) {  
    var sql = require("mssql");
    sql.Promise = require('promise');

    var dbConfig = {
        server:"ip",
        database: "db",
        user:"user",
        password: "pw"
    }

    console.log("got to the run proc functions");

    var keys = Object.keys(params);
    try {
        const pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
        const request = pool.request();
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

            if (keys[i].substring(0,6)=="Common") {
                request.input(keys[i],sql.Bit,params[keys[i]]);
                console.log("set the bit parameters");
            }
            else {
                request.input(keys[i],params[keys[i]]);
                console.log("set the other parameters");
            }
        } 
        // need to return the result of execute, not the request object
        return await request.execute("storedprocedure");
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    } finally {
        sql.close();
    }
}
```